# fstab and systemd

Tags: systemd, fstab, nfs

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.04, I have an entry in my /etc/fstab:

```
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:/storage   /storage   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

If I want to mount the NFS share, I get a systemd error:

```
mount /storage/
mount: (hint) your fstab has been modified, but systemd still uses
       the old version; use 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload.
```

When executing the systemctl command, mountig works without a problem. But now comes the issue: even after rebooting, the NFS share is not mounted and I have to enter "systemctl daemon-reload" again to mount the share manually.

Any hints why systemd even after a reboot does not recognize the fstab?

Comment: I suspect `systemd` stores a modification date of the `fstab` and compares that to the actual date; however, a `daemon-reload` fails to update this modification date. Perhaps this works: Actually modify the fstab (say, put a space somewhere), save the file, and do another reload. Possibly the new modification date gets picked up this time.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't helped. Also, I don't see that there are problems with date/time on the file - I changed it in the morning today: ls -laht  fstab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 232 May 11 11:06 fstab

Comment: After you get it mounted manually, what is the output of `grep nfs4 /etc/mtab`?  You should see a line that you can actually use and put into your `/etc/fstab` file that can assist in getting it to properly automount.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, it was Jos who brought me to the solution: the problem is that a Raspberry Pi does not have a clock and all files under /run/systemd/generator had the wrong date and time. I added now a little cron job (@reboot) which waits 5 seconds until the Raspberry has the correct time, then reloads the systemd deamons and then mounts the NFS share. Works fine ;-)

Comment: Mentioning the Raspberry Pi in your question would have helped a ton!  Glad you found your answer.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I didn't thought into that direction ;-)